# Add image to bootstrap accordion header on 'isOpenChange' event

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, accordion

I have the following accordion where i am trying to add an image to the accordion header when its clicked. Right now when i click on an accordion header this image is added to all the headers in the list. i want to add the image to only the header which is clicked. Thanks is advance

```
<accordion-group class="container-fluid p-0 acc-group " (isOpenChange)="log($event, i)" [panelClass]="customClass " *ngFor="let header of data.meters;  index as i">
    <div class="row accordian-head" accordion-heading>
        <img *ngIf="accordianOpen" src="./../../../../assets/images/green-tick.svg">
        <span class="w-100">Header</span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordian-inner-content ">
       Content here
    </div>
</accordion-group>
```

```
log(event, i){
    if(event){
      this.accordianOpen = true;
    }else{
       this.accordianOpen = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: please create a demo of your problem in code sandbox, so we easily modify your code and solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

The image is added to all the accordian because on click you are setting accordianOpen=true which satisfy's the condition for all of your image tag.

You can create a variable and store the clicked index.

```
log(event, i){
    if(event){
      this.accordianOpen = true;
      this.selectedIndex=i;
    }else{
       this.accordianOpen = false;
       this.selectedIndex=-1 //Reset the selectedIndex as per your requirement
    }
  }
```

And change the condition as follows:

```
<accordion-group class="container-fluid p-0 acc-group " (isOpenChange)="log($event, i)" [panelClass]="customClass " *ngFor="let header of data.meters;  index as i">
    <div class="row accordian-head" accordion-heading>
        <img *ngIf="accordianOpen && selectedIndex == i" src="./../../../../assets/images/green-tick.svg">
        <span class="w-100">Header</span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordian-inner-content ">
       Content here
    </div>
</accordion-group>
```